# Qt automated testing

Tags: c++, windows, qt, automated-tests

http://www.automatedqa.com/products/testcomplete/testing-qt-apps/

How would they have been able to do that?  Is there a Qt inspection library?  Standard window spy tools work in some areas, but other important areas (such as list items in a list view) are not inspectable through Windows messages.

I know there's the QtTest framework, but what I'd like is something that can access an application as a whole so that I can have automated integration testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer: http://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/qt-accessible-plugin.html

http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.3/accessible.html

Exactly what is needed to automate a UI.  Will then work with any UI automation software, which I've now learned apparently uses the accessibility API.

Comment: Example of Qt accessible plugin https://github.com/uglide/rocketpilot-driver

Answer (score 9):

[Squish](http://www.froglogic.com/products/index.php), a framework for automated GUI testing, might also be of interest to you. It supports Qt, among other things.

Comment: I use Squish daily and it's pretty neat.

Comment: Squish has a variety of cool features. It's scriptable in Python (and a couple of other languages).  It refers directly to Qt objects.

Answer (score 3):

I along with my team recently developed TUG, an open-source framework for Qt GUIs Unit Testing. It uses Qt Test. Maybe it can help you.

A video better than a thousand words:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tUis6JrycrA

Hope we can make it better together. Github repo: http://pedromateo.github.io/tug_qt_unit_testing_fw/

Answer (score 2):

Also answered in [Best approach to QT UI testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163639/best-approach-to-qt-ui-testing/4166429#4166429)

You can use OpenHMITester (OHT), that is an open-source GUI Testing tool following an open architecture that describes a non intrusive capture/replay tool based on GUI Events. It was implemented to be used in Qt; however, it may be adapted to support different windowing systems and operating systems used in the testing environment. ([Download](http://pedromateo.github.io/openhmitester/)) ([Further info](https://www.catedrasaes.org/html/projects/OHT/OHT.html))