# Best approach to QT UI testing

Tags: c++, unit-testing, user-interface, qt

I have a QT application with a bunch of menu within another menu. Each menu list item, when selected shows different forms. I would like to create another application that would test this QT application's menu if all the menu item selected are working and are showing the forms they're supposed to show.

I'm a beginner in QT, so any help as to what would be the best approach would be much appreciated.

Thanks...

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Qt automated testing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4129430/1309332)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use OpenHMITester (OHT), that is an open-source GUI Testing tool (also valid to implement RPA automations) following an open architecture that describes a non intrusive capture/replay tool based on GUI Events. It was implemented to be used in Qt; however, it may be adapted to support different windowing systems and operating systems used in the testing environment.

You can find further information at http://pedromateo.github.io/openhmitester

Comment: The link http://www.catedrasaes.org/trac/wiki/ProjectsOht is now dead.

Comment: That link is dead. This seems to be the new one: http://openhmitester.sourceforge.net/

Comment: sorry, this is the updated link: http://www.catedrasaes.org/wiki/OHT

Comment: That project is far away from running out of the box. It has inconsistent references inside of itself, boost dependencies (no problems there with latest boost) and QT dependencies (looks like latest QT SDK has different file structure and also names).

Comment: This project is being updated and recoded at http://pedromateo.github.io/openhmitester

Answer (score 6):

I recommend a tool called [Squish](http://www.froglogic.com/squish/).  There is a special Qt-only license available.

Comment: I know that my company pays for it.

Comment: You have to pay for Squish...

Comment: ... and it is quite expensive.