# Testing of Gui App on Gnome desktop

Tags: qt, testing, gnome

I have to test manually Gui App(Qt) by clicking certain menus and verifying the output text which is shown as the list view. I do not have the source code of the Gui applications.
       I am planning to write the program to generate the mouse-click events and scan the list view and test it. What are the tools available for this kind of task.

Comment: Can I ask why the source code isn't available to you?  This seems like the worst way to test and debug a program.

Comment: See also the question [Best approach to QT UI testing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4163639/1309332).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's KD Executor and Squish - details at:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq16-testing.html